# How to implement user authentication with Istio along with LDAP or other components?

Tags: networking, security, kubernetes

Can LDAP features be integrated with Istio to provide user authentication? We basically want to use Istio on top of our existing services. Our goal is to make Istio authenticate with LDAP for the list of users and their passwords. And based on this data, Istio should route the request to the appropriate service. Is there any utility through which this can be done? 
If LDAP cant be integrated with Istio, are there any other ways to have the user authentication in Istio?

Comment: Something like [keycloak](https://medium.com/@carlosedp/adding-authentication-to-your-kubernetes-front-end-applications-with-keycloak-6571097be090) combined with [istio](https://www.dangtrinh.com/2019/08/end-user-authentication-with-istio-and.html)? Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: The LDAP-like features are fine. But in my case, I need to use Istio for handling the traffic as well. So I was looking for something which can be integrated with istio.

Comment: As far as I'm concerned LDAP is not working in [istio](https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/15972#issuecomment-517340074). You can integrate [keycloak or auth0](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60484381/11977760) with istio, but it's just for authentication,  It won't work as ldap itself. If it's about auth0,keycloak and istio it will do both, handle the traffic and work on authentication.

Comment: Thank you! I guess using keycloak would be a better option and I can add LDAP users into it later

Comment: Happy to help, I made a short answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I'm concerned LDAP is not working in [istio](https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/15972#issuecomment-517340074).

---

Workaround here would be either [keycloak](https://www.keycloak.org/) or [auth0](https://auth0.com/)

You can integrate both of them with istio, but it's just for authentication, It won't work as LDAP itself, at least as far as I know.

---

A few links which might be useful

**Auth0**

- https://auth0.com/blog/securing-kubernetes-clusters-with-istio-and-auth0/

---

**Keycloak**

- https://www.dangtrinh.com/2019/08/end-user-authentication-with-istio-and.html
- https://medium.com/@carlosedp/adding-authentication-to-your-kubernetes-front-end-applications-with-keycloak-6571097be090

---

> I need to use Istio for handling the traffic as well.

If it's about auth0,keycloak and istio it will do both, handle the traffic and work on authentication.